# Spark: How long should saveAsTextFile tasks take to complete

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a basic sorting program (textFile(), sortBy(), saveAsTextFile()) on a 2 node (1 worker 1 master) spark cluster, and the execution time for tasks varies substantially.  The two jobs are sortBy() and saveAsTextFile(), with the first job taking more or less a minute for sizes up to 100GB, while the saveAsTextFile taking substantially longer (anywhere between 2-15 minutes depending on file size).

What's interesting to me is the task execution time is anywhere between 2-10 seconds per task for the saveAsTextFile job, while the sortBy job takes milliseconds.

I've been trying to find potential bottlenecks for the saveAsTextFile job by looking at the output from iostat and top.  Additionally, in the command line driver program, the second job completes in spurts; that is 16 tasks will finish at once (worker has 16 cores), then a pause of several seconds, then 16 again will finish.  This suggests that something is bottlenecking the task execution times (probably cpu?), but from looking at the monitoring command-line tools nothing is seemingly at full utilization.  Executor memory is set at 3/4 of ram, but top reads that the spark executor process never takes up over 50%.  Similarly, iostat reads that %idle is between 15-35 for cpu utilization, while %iowait is always less than 5 (indicating that no threads are waiting on disk io).  Further, network latency shouldn't be an issue since there's only one worker node.

I've messed with the spark.storage.memoryFraction, spark.local.dir, spark.shuffle.file.buffer settings, but the task execution time in the saveAsTextFile stages still takes between 2-10 seconds.  What gives?

Comment: Have you checked how much default partitions you get? What happens if you reparation the rdd/df to a small number?

Comment: Judging from the driver output, I get a ton.  Like hundreds, even after setting --conf "spark.default.parallelism=8" and textFile(file, 8) in spark-submit and the application jar, respectively.  So no luck yet on reducing the number of partitions

Comment: No. That's not going to work. The way you change the partition count of your rdd is by rdd1=rdd repartition (new number) and calling an action on rdd1.

Comment: I've tried .textFile().coalesce(256), as well as messing with the executor : memory & core ratio (increasing number of executors while decreasing executor memory and # of cores).  No luck though, performance increase is less than 10%.  Will check disk throughput and report back

Comment: `saveAsTextFile` will always be slower than any other memory operation as by definition it is spitting data onto disk, and more frequently via HDFS with all the constraints linked to HDFS (block size, replication, ..)